# How to now show empty field in my php code

Tags: php, wordpress

How to not show my code on website when my field in form is empty?

Exactly every li disappears when is empty in admin panel.

There will be ten links like that(titlebox30-1, titlebox30-2, titlebox30-XX):

[image]

```
    <li>code></li>

<?php $options = get_option('sample_theme_options30'); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $options['linkbox30-1'];?>">
<?php
  echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'.$options['titlebox30-1'].'</h2> </a>';
?>
</li>

<li>
<a href="<?php echo $options['linkbox30-2'];?>">
<?php
  echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'.$options['titlebox30-2'].'</h2> </a>';
?>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work for you:

```
<?php $options = get_option('sample_theme_options30'); ?>
<?php if ( !empty( $options['linkbox30-1'] ) ): ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $options['linkbox30-1'];?>">
<?php
  echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'.$options['titlebox30-1'].'</h2> </a>';
?>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And also you could use multidimensional array and store it in this form:

```
$options[0]['linkbox']
$options[0]['titlebox']
$options[1]['linkbox']
$options[1]['titlebox']...
```

So then you could write your code something like that:

```
<?php $options = get_option('sample_theme_options30'); ?>
<?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
  <?php if ( !empty( $option['linkbox'] ) ): ?>
   <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $option['linkbox'];?>">
    <?php
      echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'.$option['titlebox'].'</h2> </a>';
    ?>
   </li>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```